# Clock_nanosleep in linux

Tags: c, linux, signals, clock

I have some difficult with clock_nanosleep but step by step:

- my program react to SIGUSR1 sygnal
- my program should do endless    loop until get SIGALRM fro clock_nanosleep.

But it doesn't work - after send SIGUSR1 program all the time do endless loop! Anybody help ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int fd; 

void czekaj_czas()
{
   struct sigevent evp;
   struct itimerspec ts2;
   timer_t timer;
   int ret2 ;

   evp.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timer;
   evp.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
   evp.sigev_signo = SIGALRM;

   ret2 = timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&evp,&timer);
   if(ret2)
        perror("Blad funkcji timer_create");

   ts2.it_interval.tv_sec = 3;
   ts2.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
   ts2.it_value.tv_sec = 3;
   ts2.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;

   if(timer_settime(timer,0,&ts2,NULL))
        perror("timer_settime");

}

void handler_signal(int signal)
{
   sigset_t pending; // syngaly oczekujace
   int losowy_czas ;  
   struct timespec ts; 
   int ret; 
   char buf[10]; 

   int ret3; 

   ssize_t ret_out;

   int wyjsc = 1;
   int j = 0; 

   srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));    
   losowy_czas = rand() % 15 + 5;  
   ts.tv_sec = 0; 
   ts.tv_nsec = losowy_czas * 100000000;

   ret = clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,0,&ts,NULL); 


   switch(signal)
   {
       case SIGUSR1: 
        czekaj_czas();
        break;
    case SIGALRM:
            wyjsc = 0;
        break; 
    default:
        fprintf(stderr,"Zlapany zly sygnal: %d \n", signal); 
        return; 
  }


   if(ret)
    perror("Funkcja zakonczona, signal dostarczony do procesu");       


   fd = open("file.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND);
   snprintf(buf, 10, "cos cos"); 
   while(wyjsc)
    {
      ret_out = write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
      if(ret_out == -1) 
        perror("blad zapisu do bliku"); 
    }   

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i; 
   long val; 
   char *endptr; 
   struct sigaction sa;     
   int fd; 


   sa.sa_handler = &handler_signal;
   sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NODEFER ; 

   //blokowanie wszystkich innych sygnalow
   sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask); 

   if(sigaction(SIGUSR1,&sa,NULL) == -1)
   {
    perror("Nie mozna obsluzyc SIGUSR1");    
   }

   if(sigaction(SIGALRM,&sa,NULL) == -1)
   {
    perror("Nie mozna obsluzyc SIGALRM");
   }

   for(i=0; i<2000; i++)
   {
     printf("Running %i \n", i);
     sleep(1); 
   }  

   return;
}
```

Comment: “It doesn't work” is not an error description. What happened exactly? Also, what is your question?

Comment: Probably OT: Do not `printf` from a signal handler. The members of this family of functions are not guaranteed to be async-signal-save.

Comment: Same for `perror()`.

Comment: Why did you define `fd` global?

Comment: I know that printf and perror is unsafe.. Sorry for description - doesn work means that program just all the time do endless loop ! Like he never do `wyjsc = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal handler called call for `SIGALRM` does not use the same stack as the signal handler called for `SIGUSR1`. Due to this the `wyjsc` (living on the stack created for the call) for `SIGUSR1` is *not* (re-)set when `SIGALRM` gets handled.

To fix this make `wyjsc` global like for example so:

```
sig_atomic_t wyjsc = 0;
```

Comment: Thx ! This is one thigs for sure, but It still doesn't work. What more: I try to add simple unsafe `printf` to case with `SIGALRM` - and he never showed.

Comment: Ok I try one more time and works great, I just mess up in my code, thx !